# Visual Studio 2010 Add-in Handling shortcut instead my WPF APP

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, add-in, keyboard-events

I have some Add-in to VS2010 which was written in WPF. My WPF App handles some basic shortcuts.
Previously, My WPF was stand alone app, and I handled some basic command (lice Copy, paste etc) using shortcuts( Ctr+c, Ctrl,v).

Now that my app build in within VS, I can't get those keys because VS handles them and block them. 
I tried to Hook to the Keyboard event, but has much has I see, its a dirty way to do that.

Is there any way that VS want handle the shortcut,or at least my App will have the chance to handle the events first?

What is the right way to do so?

Thanks, Leon

Answer (score 1):

You should use Visual Studio commands. Visual Studio has its own key bindings, so Copy may not be mapped to Ctrl-C depending on the user's settings.

Take a look at the `IOleCommandTarget` and `VsStd2k` command sets. Depending on how you are adding your add-in, at some point, you will receive a call to an `IOleCommandTarget` implementation in your package. In order to receive a call to your `Execute` method, you first need to tell the IDE that you do handle the command (to do that, you'll need to implement `QueryStatus` and inform VS that the command is valid to be processed). The copy command is in the `GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97` command group.